# Joining 2 separate LINQ queries in C# with objectFactory

Tags: c#, sql, linq, join

I'm trying to achieve the following SQL query which works the way I need it to into LINQ. I have 2 separate SQL queries which I join and than select the product if the groups price is greater than an individual price. I'm using LINQ to objects and have an Object Factory for the Purchases and Products table.

```
select DISTINCT(a.Name) from
(select p.Prod_ID, p.Name, SUM(p.Price) as Total
from Tb_AvailableProduct p, Tb_Purchases o
where p.Prod_ID = o.Prod_ID
group by p.Prod_ID, p.Name) a
JOIN
(select p.Prod_ID, p.Price
from Tb_AvailableProduct p, Tb_Purchases o
where p.Prod_ID = o.Prod_ID) b
on a.Prod_ID = b.Prod_ID
where a.Total > b.Price
```

I have this first query in Linq, but I only want to select a Product Name if that product's group price is greater than the product's individual price.. i.e more than one product has been sold. I'm trying to accomplish this with a sum and not using a count.

```
from o in this.myObjectFactory.ThePurchases
join p in this.myObjectFactory.TheProducts.Values
on o.ProductID equals p.ProductID
where o.CustomerID == customer.CustomerID
group p by p.ProductID into query1
select new { ProductID = query1.Key, TotalPurchasesThisYear = query1.Sum (p => p.Price)});
```

Comment: whats your sql's first select query's where clause doing ?? something like this `where p.Prod_ID, p.Name`

Comment: I messed up my Group By and Where, I corrected the edits. Thanks for the catch FosterZ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should probably work (it's very similar to your SQL query):

```
var result = 
    from a in
        (
            from p in TheProducts
            join o in ThePurchases
            on p.ProductID equals o.ProductID
            group p by new { p.ProductID, p.Name, p.Price } into g
            select new
            {
                ProductID = g.Key.ProductID,
                Name = g.Key.Name,
                Total = g.Sum(i => i.Price)
            }
        )
    join b in
        (
            from p in TheProducts
            join o in ThePurchases
            on p.ProductID equals o.ProductID
            select new
            {
                ProductID = p.ProductID,
                Price = p.Price
            }
        )
    on a.ProductID equals b.ProductID
    where a.Total > b.Price
    select a.Name;

result = result.Distinct();
```

Comment: Groo that is exactly what I was looking for. I guess LINQ can be useful